# How to understand the proof of lemma2 of Jacobi's formula at wikipedia

Tags: calculus, matrices

The lemma 2 of Jacobi's formula at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) mentions:

We calculate the differential of ${\displaystyle \det X}$ and evaluate it at ${\displaystyle X=A}$ using Lemma 1, the equation above, and the chain rule:

$${\displaystyle \det '(A)(T)=\det A\ \det '(I)(A^{-1}T)=\det A\ \mathrm {tr} (A^{-1}T)}$$

My question is: how to get ${\displaystyle \det '(A)(T)=\det A\ \det '(I)(A^{-1}T) \ }$ in detailed steps?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that, if $f:E\to F $ is a differentiable map, a way to compute $df(a)(v)$ is to find a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to E$ with $\gamma(0)=a$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, and then $df(a)(v)=\frac{d}{dt}|_0f(\gamma(t))$ (this is the chain rule). Here, find a curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\gamma'(0)=T$. Then note that

$$d\det(A)(T)=\frac{d}{d t}|_0(\det(\gamma(t)))=\frac{d}{d t}|_0(\det(AA^{-1}\gamma(t)))=\det(A)\frac{d}{d t}|_0(\det(A^{-1}\gamma(t)))=\det(A)d\det(\mathrm{Id})(A^{-1}T)$$

(since $t\mapsto A^{-1}\gamma(t)$ is a curve which is $\mathrm{Id}$ in $0$ and which the derivative is $A^{-1}T$ in $0$).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!  
Another question about the proof in the same page [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula),  why $\operatorname{det}^{\prime}(A)(T) = \frac{d}{dt} det A$, when $T=\frac{dA}{dt}$ ?

Comment: If the notation $T=\frac{dA}{dt}$ means that $\gamma:t\mapsto A(t)$ is a curve with $\gamma(0)=A$ and $\gamma'(0)=T$ (I am not used to it but I think it is indeed the case), then it is for the same reason as in my answer.